# The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error

> The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be
> 'null'.
>
> Try adding a null check ('!').dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)
>
> Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext)> routeBuilders

in

```
routeBuilders[initialRoute](context),
```

even after adding the null check, it is not getting fixed, please help

```
routeBuilders![initialRoute](context),
```

code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeBuilders = _routeBuilders();
    return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      initialRoute: tabNavigatorRoot,
      onGenerateInitialRoutes: (_, initialRoute) {
        return [
          MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: RouteSettings(name: tabNavigatorRoot),
            
            builder: (context) => routeBuilders[initialRoute](context),
          )
        ];
      },
    );
  }



Map<String, WidgetBuilder> _routeBuilders() {
    return {tabNavigatorRoot: (context) => _getScreen(context, item)};
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've put the null check in the wrong place. The signature of the map accessor operator is `V? operator[](K key)`, which can return null if `key` isn't present in the map.

In your example, `routeBuilders` is always going to be a `Map<String, WidgetBuilder>` so there's no need to perform a null check there. However, you do need to perform the null check on the result of `routeBuilders[initialRoute]`, like this:

```dart
routeBuilders[initialRoute]!(context);
```

Which performs the null check on the returned closure before invoking it.

Comment: Note that the null-check from `!` is an assertion that will throw an exception if the value turns out to be `null` at runtime.  If there's a chance that the `Map` lookup could fail, use `routeBuilders[initialRoute]?.call(context)`.

Comment: Happy to help! And +1 to jamesin's caveat.